# Angular PouchDb and Auth Example

Tags: angularjs, authentication, couchdb, pouchdb

I tried great example angularjs todo app: 
https://github.com/danielzen/todo-ng-pouchdb

and now I'm trying use it with some authentication plugin, but without success ( https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication ). Todo app use some old angular-pouchdb lib.

Please do you have any tip to example where is used angular, pouchdb and auth plugin to login, signup to couchdb.

Answer (score 0):

My problems with log into CouchDb were because of wrong auth params, I didn't wrap login values into array with key *auth*.
So just example of correct call to server:

```
$scope.sync = $scope.tasks.$db.replicate.sync('http://www.server.info:5984/' + dbName, 
{live: true, "auth": {username:"john", password:"secret"}})
   .on('error', function (err) {

   });
```